# how to add auto-play in slider images using w3slider?

Tags: javascript, html, slider, autoplay

I have used a slider. But it slides manually when I click the arrow.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.3);">

    <img class="mySlides" src="img1.png" />
    <img class="mySlides" src="img2.png" />

    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>         

</div>
```

Here is my JS code:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);
plusDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > x.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = x.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

Now I want to add autoplay to slide images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added below code in your `javascript` and `html` files -

In script create `autoplay` variable like this:

```
function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var autoplay = setInterval("plusDivs(-1)", 3000);
    if (n > x.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
       slideIndex = x.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    autoplay;
  }
```

Comment: I don't need any button just make hiddenly auto-playing slider images. I edited your answer and thanks to @GreatKT its works.